# Kivy Multiple windows

Tags: android, python, kivy

I'm evaluating Kivy for android development. I need to know if is it possible to create an application with multiple windows using Kivy. I dont know for sure how android works with this kind of approach.

In c#, windows forms, we have a main window and from that we open/close another forms. How can I accomplish this approach using Kivy for android ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you mean by 'window'? In the practical sense, you can easily create different screens with kivy and switch between them, e.g. to have a menu screen, settings screen, game screen etc. Is this the kind of thing you mean? More generally, you can easily achieve any particular windowing behaviour you want within kivy.

Android itself works with activities, a particular way of choosing what is displayed, how apps move between screens, and also how apps may call particular subsets of one another (plus a lot more of course). You don't need to know about this to use kivy, it works within a single activity (plus appropriate interaction with the rest of the system), but you should read up on it if you want to understand how android manages programs and how this is different to most desktop environments.

Comment: Very precise, this is exactly what I need. Can you provide some example ? Or should I open another question. I understand the main concept you have a main.python and a file.kv(where layout goes).

Comment: Kivy comes with lots of examples, including of using a ScreenManager (a widget designed to make it easy to switch between screens, though not the only way). If you download kivy, and maybe the kivy-examples package if you don't clone from github, you can try these out directly.